# SVN to GIT push failing on Linux VM using atlassian svn migration scripts jar

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm trying to migrate a SVN repo to bitbucket GIT using the atlassian svn migration jar. 
When I run 
**java -jar svn-migration-scripts.jar verify** 
I see the following message

Git: using version 2.4.0
Subversion: using version 1.7.5
git-svn: using version 2.4.0

**Cannot connect directly to internet. This may interfere with your ability to clone Subversion repositories and push Git repositories.** //Why am i seeing this?

I am able to clone successfully but push is an issue.
When I try to push the code to bitbucket I'm seeing

**fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'**